# jQuery dialogs losing position on iPad orientation switch

Tags: jquery-ui, screen-orientation

I have several jQuery UI dialogs in my website. They are set to render in the centre of the screen.

When accessing my website on an iPad, the dialogs function fine in both orientations. But if the dialog is open and I rotate the iPad, the dialogs lose their positions.

Is this a common problem?

Is there any solution for this? Forcing the dialogs to re render on orientation switch perhaps?